# R forecast no change in future-period forecasts

Tags: r, forecasting

I am new to the R forecast() package and want to know if I am interpreting the results of forecast.ets correctly.  Essentially my point forecasts for future periods out don't change and I'm concerned that I'm using the package incorrectly.

Here is a copy-paste from my RStudio window. Note: LastRowForTrainingData == 270 and working_dataset$metric_actual[270]==99.36789)

---

```
> fit <- ets(working_dataset$metric_actual[1:LastRowForTrainingData])
> fit
ETS(A,N,N) 

Call:
ets(y = working_dataset$metric_actual[1:LastRowForTrainingData]) 

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha = 0.128 

Initial states:
 l = 99.4496 

sigma:  0.3845

  AIC      AICc       BIC 
 999.3806  999.4256 1006.5775 
> forecast(fit,h=10)

Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
271       99.72152 99.22882 100.2142 98.96799 100.4751
272       99.72152 99.22479 100.2183 98.96184 100.4812
273       99.72152 99.22080 100.2222 98.95574 100.4873
274       99.72152 99.21685 100.2262 98.94969 100.4934
275       99.72152 99.21292 100.2301 98.94368 100.4994
276       99.72152 99.20902 100.2340 98.93772 100.5053
277       99.72152 99.20515 100.2379 98.93180 100.5112
278       99.72152 99.20131 100.2417 98.92593 100.5171
279       99.72152 99.19750 100.2455 98.92010 100.5229
280       99.72152 99.19372 100.2493 98.91431 100.5287
```

---

Thank you in advance for help/confirmation that I'm not screwing this up!! :)

Comment: See http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/flat-forecasts/

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I didn't see that in your blog (which is great, by the way).  I suspected it may have been because the model recommended ANN, I forced it to MAM and saw forecasts that vary so I think I'm good now.